# Converting Lambda expression to sql query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, expression

I started a project that will allow me to create sql queries using lambda expressions.

for some reason when I'm trying the following code, the lambda injected with "Convert" method please help me understand the reason and how I can avoid it.

GroupBy function:

```
public QueryBuilder<T> GroupBy(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] expression)
{
    _groupBy.AddRange(expression);
    return this;
}
```

Usage example:

```
query.GroupBy(x=>x.IntExample,x=>x.StringExample)
```

from the immediate:

```
 expression
 {System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Tests.Example,object>>[2]}
 [0]: {x => Convert(x.IntExample)}
 [1]: {x => x.StringExample}
```

Fill free to fork the project:
https://github.com/matanshidlov/Lambda-To-Sql/tree/master/Lambda-To-Sql

Comment: try this query.GroupBy(x=> x.IntExample, x.StringExample)

Comment: I cant do this, that code doesn't pass compilation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` is a reference type. `int` is a value type. In order to convert an `int` into an `object`, and thus into a reference type, the `int` has to be **boxed**. Boxing involves creating a reference type object as a wrapper around the `int`. This is what `Convert` does.

See: [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
and also: [Expression.Convert Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.convert(v=vs.110).aspx)